# Authenticate a user based on a token and not through mysql table

Tags: jwt, laravel-5.3

round 2: trying to make this clearer:

I have two totally and completely separate services (both laravel 5.3).

One is an authentication service that has access to a user mysql database, permissions and role.

The other is a resource service. It couldn't care less about the user table and does not have access to any user table.

That means that any type of Auth::loginById()... would never work in this service because there is no user table.

I want to use JWT to have users access the resource service API, and have the user Auth to act as if a user is authenticated - but again - all I have are the claims inside the JWT - no user table. The claims include some information about the user - id, name, etc. I want to do something like this:

```
$userObj = JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload()->claims; // { id:4, name: Birdman, email: birdy414141@gmail.com} 
Auth::login($userObj)
```

and then have access to the user object like usual

```
echo Auth::user()->name // Birdman
```

Has anyone tried anything like this?

I have found that doing this more or less works:

```
$u = new User();
$u->user_id = (JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload()->get('sub'));
$u->name = (JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload()->get('name'));
```

Obviously I can't $u->save() here because again - there is no user database.

I can do this though:

```
Auth::login($u);
```

and then I can later call Auth::user()->name properly...

I'm asking if I'm doing something exotic here or is this good stuff. Where will this fail?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking about the security concerns about your architecture, or about the implementation to include and extract those claims?

Comment: @pedrofb tried again to make things clearer.